# What causes a change of mission type during a play-through?

Tags: warframe

I was doing a mobile defense mission on Sedna, and after the second defense point, Lotus said something to the effect of "Change of plans. Ignore the original mission and eliminate all enemies," and the mission changed to an exterminate instead. What caused this change?

Comment: Side note: If Lotus tells you to change objectives, do so.  For example, if the original mission was Mobile Defense, do NOT activate the next mobile defense node.  If you **do** and it gets destroyed, you **will** lose the mission despite it no longer being your objective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a type of [Second Primary Objective](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Mission/Secondary_Objectives).  These were added [a while ago](https://forums.warframe.com/topic/2803-update-53-blazing-embers/) (listed as "mid mission surprise changeups") and were designed to "make things more interesting."

After complaints, the frequency of this event was drastically reduced, which lends itself to the idea that it is triggered by something, but it appears to be completely random, and usually decided at the start of the mission.